# Is it true that unknown publisher warning will show up even with a signed certificate for all new publishers?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, code-signing

I have just created my first piece of software that I would like to share with the world, after checking it out on a couple other computers I remembered the unknown publisher warning that pops up for software that does not have their software digitally signed.

So after reading up I foundout that getting an authenticode signing certificate will remove this warning, although after reading more someone pointed out that even if you have a signed certificate from a reputable supplier the users will still be prompted with the same warning if the publisher is new and has not released software before.

I just want to verify this is true. I am using advanced installer for deployment.(don't think it matters though)

This is for .net software created in visual studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that isn't true. Unknown Publisher only shows up for unsigned files or files that have been signed by a certificate issued from a non-trusted source (such as generating one on your own).

I have some screenshot examples up of the differences in the prompts you'll see between signed and unsigned files at http://codesigning.ksoftware.net

Drop me an email and I'll give you (and anyone else) an additional discount coupon if you decide to purchase one.

Comment: Wow that's actually great you posted here, I was going to purchase one from your website today. I had a hard time wrapping my head around how much cheaper you offer comodo certificates than anyone else.